# Extract Worldclim Data Using R without rgdal package

Tags: r, gis, raster, rgdal

I have some geographic data points (latitude and longitude), and I want to extract 1km resolution climate data (max, min, mean temperature) for them.  There is a nice coded example of how to do this in R [here](https://gist.github.com/kgturner/6643334):

The problem is that it requires the 'rgdal' package, and unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with Mavericks, which is what I'm using.  I tried the work-around for installing 'rgdal' [here](http://www.janosgyerik.com/installing-rgdal-in-r-on-os-x-mavericks/), but without success.

Anyone know a workaround for installing rgdal on Mavericks?  Or anyone familiar with working with Worldclim in R and know another package or other work-around?

Here is the identifier, lat/long for the sites:

```
 id<-c('SV2050','SV515','SV3250')
 lat<-c(9.53333,9.49989,9.55875)
 long<-c(-83.8167,-84.0315,-83.7434)
 cbind(id,lat,long)
```

Comment: What format would you like the data in? I can get it on a VM and put it up for you to download in whatever format you prefer.

Comment: `gdal` & `rgdal` work perfectly under mavericks, I use it all the time. I use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and did a `brew install gdal` then installed the `rgdal` package without incident. You can also try it with the framework on the [OS X QGIS](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) page.

Comment: Good to know that you got them working under mavericks.  At cran [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) they just say it's not available for mavericks.  Thanks.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Generally one needs to understand how to manage UNIX environment variables and configure files in order to have external packages interface with binary versions of R packages on the Mac. You might do user2860703 a favor by laying down the necessary steps to set up the PATH and any symlinks to make the non-standard homebrew conventions be compatible with the defaults that the R authors expect.

Comment: @hd1 That would be amazing! It's only a few geographic data points, so a csv or text file of the monthly temperature data (max, min, mean) would be great. Would it also be possible to do precipitation?

Comment: Where is the source data?

Comment: @BondedDust it's literally "download/install homebrew" then `brew install gdal` and instal the `rgdal` pkg. No symlinks. No extra steps.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Then, are you using a compiled version of R that you got from the homebrew repository? Many people have had incompatibility problems caused by mixing of package installation using one of MacPorts, DarwinPorts, and homebrew.

Comment: I use stock R from CRAN mirrors for Mavericks. I only use `homebrew` for all *nix package management and it's as stable as `apt-get` on Ubuntu, `yum` on RedHat/CentOS. If you don't mix-and-match, it's a really straightforward install.

Comment: @hd1 I added the data to the question.  You rock.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks for the additional information.  I imagine you install the rgdal and gdal packages in the same directory as the packages from CRAN?

Comment: I suppose you could say they are "close" since they are both in the `/Library/Frameworks/` tree. There are in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/` - directory ... where rgdal expects to find it.

Comment: Here lies the data in [Rdata format](http://hasan.d8u.us/26172969.Rdata). Save it somewhere, `load(file.you.just.saved)` and whatever data will be in the `geo.coords` dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you need the rgdal package depends on the file format of the raster data. You can download the WorldClim data in a generic binary format (BIL). The raster package can read these without rgdal.